# How can I prevent all USB mass storages from mounting?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I want to prevent every kind of USB mass storage from mounting using [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules.

Already I can detect all of USB mass storage devices connected to my system using the following rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", SUBSYSTEM=="block" KERNEL=="sd[b-h]1"
```

But how can I prevent them from mounting?

I know I have to set the authorized file of its relevant USB device to zero! But how can I find the USB device path? The $DEVPATH gives me the path of storage device block for example sdb1!

I have an application which should give permission to some of USB mass storage devices. So the used method for blocking the USB mass storage devices should not be very static!

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 3):

The following rule prevents all except the first partition from being auto-mounted:

```
# Rule: Only mount first partition found on /dev/sd* (USB) devices.
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*[2-9]", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY}="1"
```

Reason: In USB disks with multiple partitions, I only want to automount the first one. I manually mount the others, if I want them.

You should be able to substitute the partition matcher with KERNEL=="sd*", to get:

```
# Rule: Do not automount any partitions found on /dev/sd* (USB) devices.
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY}="1"
```

This prevents auto-mounting, which you can then manually manage.

I have only tested this on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to blacklist the `usb-storage` kernel module. This will only work if it has been compiled as a module however, rather than directly into the kernel. You can check with `modprobe -n usb-storage.ko`, or by looking for it in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/

If it's compiled as a module, you can black list it by adding an entry to  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist(.conf) For Debian, see [this guide](http://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting)

Comment: What kind of entry should i add to this file? could you give me an example?

Comment: This method is too static, i need to manage the blocked usb storages! i have an application which can give permission to some usb storages to mount! I think the only way is using udev! do you know how?

Comment: You need to edit your question then, because your question said `I want to prevent every kind of usb mass storage from mounting`, not `I have an application which can give permission to some usb storage to mount`.